# Hylix carbon fork and compression plug

Tags: steerer, carbon-fork, torque

I have an Origin8 compression plug 90mm long with recommended torque of **8Nm**. But it can't be inserted fully into the Hylix carbon fork I bought online as there's lots of epoxy blocking the tube in the last 10mm of space the plug requires to be fully inserted (given the length to which the steerer has been cut, ~7 inches, 17.5cm). The obstruction extends up to about 9cm above the fork crown. Rather than try to drill some of that stuff out, I bought a slightly shorter plug that is only 81mm in length.

The recommended torque for the 81mm plug is **10Nm** (per the manufacturer's website).  I can't find any technical info on Hylix, so I'm wondering if 10Nm is OK, as it is a good deal higher than recommended torque on the Origin8.

The [Whisky compression plug instructions](https://whiskyparts.co/files/tech/Whisky_Instructions_Compression_Plug.pdf) say to tighten their plug to only **1.6Nm**, so clearly there must be quite a difference in the design of these plugs, or quite a wide range of opinion on the proper torque, or that number is a typo.

Is there any way the consumer can make fact-based judgments on such things? Is the thickness of the steerer tube wall the determining factor? It is 2.65mm

> “People often make the mistake of thinking that the plug is solely to
> preload the headset bearings,” he [Raoul Luescher of Luescher Teknik in Melbourne, Australia] said. “However, due to most carbon
> steerers not having much in the way of hoop strength, due to the
> difficulty in laying down 90-degree fibers in a production environment
> with the process used, the plug is important to contain the hoop loads
> from the stem clamp. Thus I do not recommend ultralight or poorly
> designed or installed plugs in most steerer tubes as we see lots of
> cases of delamination caused by the stem clamp.”

https://cyclingtips.com/2017/05/cane-creek-eenut-review/

Comment: *compression plug 90mm long*  Get a shorter compression plug.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Read before offering advice. I did get a shorter plug.

Comment: All the compression plug does is hold the top cap in place while you tighten the clamp bolts on the stem.  It's literally useless after that.

Comment: @Andrew Henle:  Why do compression plugs come in different lengths?

Comment: To get people to pay extra for a part the manufacturer spent $0.30 to make.  How many bikes with short compression plugs have failed steerer tubes?

Comment: @AndrewHenle  See the edit.

Comment: So someone with a vested interest in selling such a product posted garbage to the internet that promotes that product? Imagine that... Again - how many failed steerer tubes do you see?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Do you have a real answer to the question why compression plugs are available in different lengths?   Because people will buy them seems too facile.

Comment: To get people to ask questions about them on the internet?  It's a !(&%(!@&#%!@# compression plug - you screw it in to hold your stem in place while you tighten your stem's clamp bolts, then you go ride your bike.  You are ***WAAAAAYYY*** overthinking this.

Comment: @AndrewHenle And your posts strike me as coming from someone who WAAAAYYY underthinks things. So I guess we're at an impasse. I just can't take your remarks as authoritative because you insist they are. You dismissed Luescher out of hand as a huckster posting "garbage".

Comment: Yeah, all those upvotes you're getting....  Do you really think in a sport where there are people who drop $5,000 on a DuraAce Di2 bike, then put $3000 aero wheels on it, all to go putz around on a MUP at 20 km/h that there aren't hucksters who aim for lower-hanging fruit with cheaper useless bling?  There isn't one manufacturer of CF forks with CF steerer tubes that would be in business if this piece of  bling were actually needed for safe cycling.  You'll notice no one has contradicted anything I've posted - with almost 50 views, no one's disagreed with me, nor upvoted your question...

Comment: @AndrewHenle  So your position is that the compression plug is absolutely "useless bling" and that the stem could be safely clamped to the carbon steerer tube without such a plug?  If so, may I simply ask you what you base this opinion on? Is it experimental evidence? Anecdotal evidence? Engineering training? What?

Comment: Or is your position that *long* compression plugs are useless bling?

Comment: LOL.  I sure hope you don't have a carbon fiber seatpost.  You know, a hollow carbon fiber tube clamped onto by something and  ***without*** some piece of metal inside, which you apparently think is necessary for a carbon fiber tube that gets clamped to function safely. Because that carbon fiber seatpost - ***without that internal metal reinforcement*** - is supporting a whole lot more weight than the steerer tube, and it's just sitting there waiting to break off and stab you right in the nether regions. Why, it's gonna snap right off just like all those steerer tubes without that huge plug!

Comment: https://www.newyorkbikelawyer.com/blog/2013/august/giant-bike-recall-due-to-defective-seat-posts/     https://www.outsideonline.com/2311816/carbon-fiber-bike-accidents-lawsuits   https://www.consumeraffairs.com/bicycle-recalls?page=2

Comment: I get it - you spent money on some bling that's useless.  Guess what?  There's nothing you can do to convince me you didn't do that.  I think you're trying to convince yourself more than anything.

Comment: Think what you like. I'm trying to find out what is considered "best practice" in regard to torque of compression plug, since it varies quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

- The plugs only purpose is to be strong enough to not move up when you tighten the headset down.
- The steerer will be clamped by the stem, so the stem will reinforce the steerer once clamped.
- The top cap recommended torque is probably 4-6Nm.
- Support the top of the steerer from crushing. Although it is often recomended to add a 5mm spacer ontop of the stem so the top of the stem in not flush with the top of the steerer to help with this.

So my advice if you're worried about the steerer's integrity would be tighten the plug to a lower spec than you think and try it with the top cap, only tighten the plug further if the top cap pulls it up.

As the stem will clamp the steerer with more force than the plug expands with, you shouldn't worry about the plug damaging your steerer as you ride.

So, torque specs are in general only advisory in the sense that they will a min and max value. If you're careful and mindful of what you're doing, you don't need to look at the plug torque at all, just tighen enough so it doesn't ride up, making sure at no point you pass a damaging amount of torque (more than 10-13Nm in this case).

Comment: I suspect the plug is also to support the steerer tube from the inside, and the generous length means that support goes down below the top bearing.

Comment: Only at the top, I will edit to add this, you will destroy the threads on the stem way before you start crushing the steerer further down from the top.

Comment: @Criggie It might very well do that, but as I've yet to see a single failed steerer tubes on all those bikes that use short compression plugs, I'd say it's a useless feature.

Comment: I would say a 90/80mm plug is way overkill. Don't need anything bigger than 40ish-mm really.

Comment: @abdnChap  My underlying question is, in the absence of guidance from the manufacturer (who might be unknown) how does the  DIYer  come by the knowledge that torque in excess of 13Nm can damage a particular carbon steerer?

Comment: @abdnChap  Why do compression plugs come in different lengths?